# How to render html and javascript from express?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a very simple express app that has two routes, one that should render html, and one that should render a javascript file.  Ideally, I'd like to have each in different folders, a `./views` folder for html and an `./assets/javascripts` folder for js.  I'm wondering the best way to do this?  Here is what I have so far:

```
var express = require('express')
  , app     = express()
  , fs      = require('fs')

['html', 'js'].forEach(function(extension) {
  app.engine(extension, function(filePath, options, callback) {
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, content) {
      if (err) throw new Error(err)
      return callback(null, content.toString())
    })
  })
})

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Do I need to be doing this?  Where can I find more information?

Comment: where is your second route??? And you don't need to have routes for static javascript files!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to make routes that respond to a static file. Use:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/path-to/your/static-file');
});
```

If you just want to set assets for your project. You should do:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And then use a dedicated `public` directory for your assets.

(If this wasn't the answer you were looking for ask me in comments what you want!)

Answer (score 1):

For static JavaScript files, you just need to set your public assets folder, as such:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I suggest you read the API documentation further: http://expressjs.com/api.html